# Best practice: MongoDB Panache entity one-to-many relationship handling in Quarkus?

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

The [Quarkus Guide on using MongoDB with Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache) does unfortunately not mention what is considered the best practice dealing with one-to-many relations of entities. Note: I would like to model the dependent sub-document, but as an entity on its own. The MongoDB site demonstrates this pattern in: [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) so that you would have to lookup in your repository all entities linked to the parent ID.

Does Quarkus (Panache) provide currently any means to make the lookup more convenient?

PS: There seems to be an [open enhancement request from May 2020](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9210) to automatically fetch the referenced entities.

Comment: In general, [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) is the way to query with a "join" operation. So, you can run a native query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As informed by @loicmathieu there is no direct way to do `populate()` in quarkus as you are able to do it in mongoose.
If you set `mongoose.set('debug', true)` then you can check in console that first

- `find` query on collection is executed
- `in` query on reference collection is executed.

Example json document:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612f6c5c081d0796761ec2e4"),
    "content" : "cannot restart Mongodb even when memory space is available",
    "created_by" : ObjectId("612cb8608d22afb0e404adf6"),
    "tags" : [ 
        ObjectId("612f6c5c081d0796761ec2e2")
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-01T12:04:44.361Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-10T05:30:51.384Z"),
    "__v" : 2,
    "likes" : [],
    "replies" : []
}
```

Tag Document

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612f6c5c081d0796761ec2e2"),
    "name" : "mongodb",
    "created_by" : ObjectId("612cb8608d22afb0e404adf6"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-09-01T12:04:44.358Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2021-09-01T12:04:44.358Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

And finally user document

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612cb8608d22afb0e404adf6"),
    "username" : "silentsudo",
    "password" : "sosimplebcrypted",
    "name" : "Ashish",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

To get all documents i execute following query:

```js
exports.getRecentTweets = async () => {
    return Tweet.find()
        .populate('created_by', '_id name username mediaId')
        .populate('tags', '_id name')
        .sort({'createdAt': -1});
}
```

Mongoose internally executing this in the following manner

```
Mongoose: tweets.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }, projection: {} })
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("612cb8608d22afb0e404adf6"), new ObjectId("612f57ca9ea5c5cabbd89b38"), new ObjectId("612f57ae9ea5c5cabbd89b32"), new ObjectId("6134cb55328b793a1dacb9c2"), new ObjectId("612cb86a8d22afb0e404adfc") ] }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: { _id: 1, name: 1, username: 1, mediaId: 1 }})
Mongoose: tags.find({ _id: { '$in': [ new ObjectId("6144d9ef02f6da33f39fe134"), new ObjectId("612f6c5c081d0796761ec2e2"), new ObjectId("612f6e9f081d0796761ec343"), new ObjectId("612dc4623c401072c8098a84"), new ObjectId("612f6cb1081d0796761ec2f1"), new ObjectId("612f6c72081d0796761ec2eb"), new ObjectId("612f6e5b081d0796761ec337"), new ObjectId("612f6e42081d0796761ec330"), new ObjectId("612f6df9081d0796761ec320"), new ObjectId("612f6e0a081d0796761ec328"), new ObjectId("612f6de8081d0796761ec316"), new ObjectId("612f6de8081d0796761ec319"), new ObjectId("612f6dc9081d0796761ec30c"), new ObjectId("612f6dc9081d0796761ec30f"), new ObjectId("612f6db0081d0796761ec303"), new ObjectId("612f6db0081d0796761ec306"), new ObjectId("612f6cc7081d0796761ec2f7") ] }}, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, projection: { _id: 1, name: 1 }})
```

I was experimenting `ab tool` for benchmarking. So i decided to go with quarkus as i never built any production application using it before. So i quickly created model and arrived at this thread only to know there is no direct way to achieve populate in java based driver. But we can use `$lookup`  with aggregation pipeline what we need. First and simplest way is to use mongodb compass tool to build the query and then simply export the result in java language. my json query to produce output similar to populate query looked like this.

```json
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$tags', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'tags', 
      'localField': 'tags', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'tweet_tags'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$tweet_tags', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'content': {
        '$first': '$content'
      }, 
      'user': {
        '$first': '$created_by'
      }, 
      'tags': {
        '$push': '$tweet_tags'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'users', 
      'localField': 'user', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'createdByUser'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$createdByUser', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'createdByUser.password': null
    }
  }
]
```

Which when converted into equivalent java gives

```java
public static List<Document> getTweetByUserQuery() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Document("$unwind",
                            new Document("path", "$tags")
                                    .append("preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true)),
                    new Document("$lookup",
                            new Document("from", "tags")
                                    .append("localField", "tags")
                                    .append("foreignField", "_id")
                                    .append("as", "tweet_tags")),
                    new Document("$unwind",
                            new Document("path", "$tweet_tags")
                                    .append("preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", true)),
                    new Document("$group",
                            new Document("_id", "$_id")
                                    .append("content",
                                            new Document("$first", "$content"))
                                    .append("user",
                                            new Document("$first", "$created_by"))
                                    .append("tags",
                                            new Document("$push", "$tweet_tags"))),
                    new Document("$lookup",
                            new Document("from", "users")
                                    .append("localField", "user")
                                    .append("foreignField", "_id")
                                    .append("as", "createdByUser")),
                    new Document("$unwind",
                            new Document("path", "$createdByUser")
                                    .append("preserveNullAndEmptyArrays", false)),
                    new Document("$set",
                            new Document("createdByUser.password",
                                    new BsonNull())));
        }
```

quarkus Controller code as below:

```java
@Path("/hello")
public class ExampleResource {
    @Inject
    private MongoClient mongoClient;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<Object, Object> hello() {
        MongoCollection<Tweet> tweetsCollection = mongoClient.getDatabase("simple-node-js")
                .getCollection("tweets", Tweet.class);


        List<Document> groupByQueryUser = Tweet.GroupByIdDetails.getTweetByUserQuery();

        MongoCollection<Document> collections = mongoClient.getDatabase("simple-node-js")
                .getCollection("tweets");
        AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = collections.aggregate(groupByQueryUser);
        List<Document> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Document value : aggregate) {
            System.out.println(value);
            data.add(value);
        }

        return Map.of("size", data.size(), "data", data);
    }


}
```

There are many other things needs to be done with the response like removing unwanted fields but this ways i could achieve same result on node+mongoose api(except few more things which i skipped here)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a non-relational database, that why there is no one-to-many relation support for it.

> I would like to model the dependent sub-document,

I didn't follow, sub-document is supported, you can just create a separate POJO and use it as an attribute of you entity.

What is not supported, is to automatically load referenced entity from one collection to another, as you pointed out there is an opened enhancement request for it support, you can give feedback on it (or vote for it via +1).

Currently, for referenced entity, you need to create two entities / repositories and make the fecth manually.

Comment: For sure I didn't want to either discuss on the nature of MongoDB nor to complain about Panache in any ways (nor be trained on how github works). FYI: From the quarkus github template I was pointed out to ask questions at stackoverflow.  Regarding my Q: I was thinking something around what is called "populate" in Mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html and was just wondering about how people leverage MongoDB with panache-quarkus in an idomatic way.

Comment: There is no such thing as Mongoose populate in MongoDB with Panache.
In the Java land, The idiomatic way for this type of functionality is to use two different entities / repositories and use an agregate service on top of them to deal with the relation.